# How in PhpStorm in Project Files to show size/modification date of file?

Tags: phpstorm

If there is a way in PhpStorm 2021.1 in Project Files area to show size and modification date of any file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just enable `View | Appearance | Details in Tree Views` from the main menu.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-tool-window.html#show-filesize-timestamp

[image]